# subView not visible despite using bringSubviewToFront: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've created a UIView, let's call it `viewFromIB`, in Interface Builder and have hidden it when my ViewController loads. I am creating another UIView , let's call it `modalViewType`, through code and adding it as subView of `self.navigationController.view`:

```
UIView *modalViewType = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
modalViewType.opaque = NO;
modalViewType.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6f];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:modalViewType];
```

Now I am unhiding `viewFromIB`, adding `viewFromIB` as subView of `modalViewType` and bringing `viewFromIB` to front by using `bringSubviewToFront:` method. But `viewFromIB` is not becoming visible though am able to see `modalViewType`. Here is the code:

```
viewFromIB.hidden = NO;
viewFromIB.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
viewFromIB.center = CGPointMake(modalViewType.frame.size.width/2, modalViewType.frame.size.height/2);
[modalViewType addSubview:viewFromIB];
[modalViewType bringSubviewToFront:viewFromIB];
```

FYI, this used to work fine in iOS6 but now throwing tantrums with iOS7. Please let me know if any other info is required. Thanks a lot.

Update: If I don't use `modalViewType` UIView and just unhide `viewFromIB` and `bringSubviewToFront:` it on `self.view` it is working fine. There is issue only when am trying to add subview of `modalViewType`. My subView's frame seems completely logical.

Comment: try, self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewFromIB];

Comment: @karthika I've already tried this. It doesn't work as  `[modalViewType addSubview:viewFromIB];` have changed the superview of viewFromIB to modalViewType

Answer (score 0):

If the `viewFromIB` is from Interface Builder it is possibly already added to some superview. I am not sure what the defined behaviour of `addSubview:` is for a view that has already been added to another view as a subview.

Maybe you could try calling `removeFromSuperview` first.

Also, check the size of your `viewFromIB` - iOS7 has been known to resize stuff in unexpected ways.

Comment: `addSubview:` method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview. I've check size of `viewFromIB` and it seems to be fine.

Comment: Still. Maybe when you are setting the `center` it is actually doing this on the previous superview. After it is removed, the new frame is perhaps not defined.

Comment: Yeah, line of code where am doing center aligned seems to be of no use. I've removed it but in vain. If I don't add `viewFromIB` as a subView of `modalViewType` then am able to see `viewFromIB` in background (as subView of `self.view`) but as soon as i add that as subView of `modalViewType`, it  disappears. `addSubView:` method is working fine as when I see subviews of `modalViewType` (using `po modalViewType.subviews`), `viewFromIB` UIView is present that too with right `Frame`.

Comment: What frame does `po modalViewType.subviews` report for your `viewFromIB`?

Comment: Here is entire printed output:  (<UIView: 0xa92e390; frame = (20 37; 280 450); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0xa92e3f0>>
)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this line of code:

```
viewFromIB.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

was causing the trouble. `masksToBounds` method indicates whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds. To my knowledge this shouldn't have any impact on UIView's own visibility. I tried to find root cause of the issue but could not :(
Anyways, just wanted to share that removing this line sorted out my issue and now my subview is visible. FYI: using this line in iOS6 never had any adverse impact on visibility of UIView.